# the From<&String> trait is not implemented for the type String

Tags: string, rust, ownership

I'm going off of [this](http://hermanradtke.com/2015/05/06/creating-a-rust-function-that-accepts-string-or-str.html) article in an attempt to write a function that accepts both a String and a &str, but I'm running into a problem. I have the following function:

```
pub fn new<S>(t_num: S) -> BigNum where S: Into<String> {
    let t_value = t_num.into();
    let t_digits = t_value.len();
    BigNum { value: t_value, digits: t_digits }
}
```

`BigNum` is a simple struct, the problem however is when I attempted to call this with a `&collections::string::String` I get an error:

```
let line = "123456".to_string()
let big = bignum::BigNum::new(&line)
```

---

```
main.rs:23:15: 23:34 error: the trait `core::convert::From<&collections::string::String>` is not implemented for the type `collections::string::String` [E0277]
main.rs:23     let big = bignum::BigNum::new(&line);
```

I was under the impression that a `&String` will be implicitly broken down into a `&str` no? And in that case the `Into` trait would convert the `&str` into a String I could then use. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're conflating two different processes.

First, there's coercion; in particular, [`Deref` coercion](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/deref-coercions.html).  This happens when the compiler sees that you have a `&U`, but you *want* a `&T`.  Provided there is an `impl Deref<Target=T> for U`, it will do the coercion for you.  This is why a `&String` will coerce to a `&str`.

*However*, this *does not* come into play when the compiler is substituting generic type parameters.  When you say `BigNum::new(&line)`, what the compiler sees is that you're trying to pass a `&String` where it expects an `S`; thus, `S` must be `&String`, thus `S` must implement `Into<String>` and... oh no!  It doesn't!  **BOOM!**  Coercion is never triggered because the compiler never *needs* to coerce anything; unfulfilled type constraints are a different problem.

In this *particular* case, what you should do depends on your circumstances:

- You can just pass a `String`; use `line` or `line.clone()`.  This is the most efficient in that you can always pass in an owned `String` you no longer need and avoid an extra allocation.
- You can instead take an `&S` with `S: ?Sized + AsRef<str>`, which doesn't allow you to pass an owned string, but if you're always going to allocate anyway, this may be more ergonomic.

Here's an example of both in action:

```rust
use std::convert::AsRef;

fn main() {
    take_a_string(String::from("abc"));
    // take_a_string(&String::from("abc")); // Boom!
    take_a_string("def");

    // take_a_string_ref(String::from("abc")); // Boom!
    take_a_string_ref(&String::from("abc"));
    take_a_string_ref("def");
}

fn take_a_string<S>(s: S)
where S: Into<String> {
    let s: String = s.into();
    println!("{:?}", s);
}

fn take_a_string_ref<S: ?Sized>(s: &S)
where S: AsRef<str> {
    let s: String = s.as_ref().into();
    println!("{:?}", s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by DK., this is not possible with the Rust `Into` trait, because of the missing implementation of `Into<String> for &String`. I couldn't find the reasons behind this, but you can create your own Trait to solve this:

```
pub trait IntoString {
    fn into(self) -> String;
}

impl IntoString for &String {
    fn into(self) -> String {
        self.to_string()
    }
}
impl IntoString for &str {
    fn into(self) -> String {
        self.to_string()
    }
}

impl IntoString for String {
    fn into(self) -> String {
        self
    }
}

pub fn new<S>(t_num: S) -> BigNum where S: IntoString {
    let t_value = t_num.into();
    let t_digits = t_value.len();
    BigNum { value: t_value, digits: t_digits }
}
```